# How to scan a big list to find if all elements match the ones of a second, smaller, list?

Tags: python, list, boolean

I'm hvaing a hard time with a problem which I thought was pretty simple.
I have two lists:

1. A small one, that looks like this:

```
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E']
```

2. The second list is much bigger, going on for about 800 elements. It looks like this:

```
list2 = ['E', 'B', 'F', 'A', 'C', 'N'...]
```

I want to scan list2 and see if all of its elements are the same as the ones in list1. If they are different, I want to see which are the elements that differ and cancel them from list2. In this example, I want to print "F" and "N" from list2 and cancel them.

I tried:

```
found = False
lenght2 = len(list2)
i = 0
for j in list1:
  for i in range(0, lenght2):
     if i != j:
        found = True
        #I don't know how to cancel i
        print(i)
        i = i + 1
     break
```

However, the whole thing does not work.
Is there anyone who could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  could  go through all of list2 then check if it is in list one, like this:

```
for i in range(len(list2)):
  if list2[i] in list1:
    pass
  else:
    #Cancel list2[i] ? Or whatever.
```

Answer (score 0):

### Keep it simple:

There's no need to use nested loops here -- you are removing elements from `list2`, based on information from `list1`, so loop through `list2`.

```
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
list2 = ['E', 'B', 'F', 'A', 'C', 'N']

for e in list2[:]:
    if e not in list1:
        list2.remove(e)
print(list2)
```

This code loops through `list2` and checks  for each element (`e`) if it occurs in `list1`. If not, it removes it from `list2`.

Note: the use of `list2[:]` here rather than `list2` is due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating).

---

### Or use a list comprehension:

```
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
list2 = ['E', 'B', 'F', 'A', 'C', 'N']

list2 = [e for e in list2 if e in list1]
print(list2)
```

See more about how list comprehensions work [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

---

In both cases, you should get:

```
['E', 'B', 'A', 'C']
```